# Joining Points to Lines in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, network-analyst, snapping

I have a shapefile of line data (roads) and one of point (villages) data. In an ideal situation all the points should be connected to a line. The data that I have doesn't obey this. I need to join all the points to the nearest line using a straight line. What function can I use in ArcGIS to obtain this. I need this data to carry out the Closest Facility solver in Network Analyst in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network Analyst will automatically snap points (incidents or facilities) to the nearest network edge [when you add them](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004800000005000000) if configured to do so; there's no need to do so beforehand.

If you want to force it, [Snap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000) could be used (requires Standard or Advanced license, directly modifies data so run it on a copy).

If you actually want to draw a new line to represent a network edge straight from the point to the nearest existing network edge, you might take a look at [Arcgis 10: Point layer, polygon line layer, draw points to the nearest polygon point or other nearest line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34972/) Depending on how far your points might be from the network, this might be a good idea or required as I'm pretty sure the distances in the solver result will only be along the network, and not include the 'snapping' distance.

Comment: The attempts I have made, the calculated distance does not touch the village, but terminates at point beside the village. What I need is the distance to terminate at the village point. So the road distance is calculated first then a straight line distance is added( from road edge to the village)

Comment: @PeterMMacharia Then you'll need to use the method outlined at the linked question to create new lines/network edges. Be aware that it will be a straight-line distance, not accounting for any obstacles in the way. Given the size of your dataset this rough approximation may be the only option. Otherwise considering rivers or other obstacles in determining the nearest accessible road might require additional work or manual digitizing.

Comment: Thank you, It has worked out, I have my dataset ready for the analysis